# Seeking Guidance

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

I'm new with this and not certain what platform to use to achieve my desired outcome (i.e. php, javascript, etc.), but I'm a fast learner.

I add videos to my YouTube channel daily. After this I update two separate webpages where I manually embed the newest video URL.

**Question:**
I would like to automate this work process. What is the best approach (i.e. CSS, Javascript, PHP, etc.) that I can use to "get" the most current YouTube video URL and embed it into my webpage(s) automatically?

I hope I explained this properly. Let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer!!!

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Get link of latest video on your Channel**:

You can request from Youtube, a Channel's feed using

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=XXXXX
```

Where `XXXXX` is the channel's ID (as shown in browser's address bar).

The first entry in the XML document is the latest video.
Use Javascript **Fetch** API to load the XML or else have a JS function to call a PHP script that gives/reads back this XML document.

After correct loading, you'll have a **String** (text) copy of that same document existing in some variable that you put it into. The idea here is to edit the text by code (instead of highlighting and replacing the URL in a text editor). The code should find and replace the URL. The code should then save the edited text as a new HTML file (overwrite the old one using PHP)

With Javascript, either use its **String** functions to extract the URL or follow some tutorial about parsing XML to extract data.

**(2) To update the webpages**: (use PHP)

- Option 1 is to load the old page and use PHP **String** functions to replace text of old link with latest new link. Then write the edited text as file (overwrite older HTML file)
- Option 2 is to have a "template" document already stored as String in your code. Then simply replace (or add if needed) the URL of new video. Then have PHP save the text of String as an HTML file, overwriting the old `.html`.

Comment: Will this same logic work getting the latest video from a PLAYLIST?

Comment: For latest addition to a playlist you have to check the `<updated>` value if your playlist is mixed around (_eg:_ latest upload is positioned in the middle of other items). However, if you add items  in sequence then you can just go to bottom of playlist (last entry). Note there is a limit to how long the feed can be, so don't expect it to list 365 items if you upload everyday. I can't remember the limit (maybe 50). Either make a new playlist when XML feed limit is reached or just get an account with Youtube Developers (there is still a daily limit on requests)

Comment: PS: For the easiest way... when you upload a video, couldn't you also just add it to **two** playlists (the first one is the expected playlist to add it to, then have a second one maybe called "latest" (and can be private, visible only to those who known direct link to it). In this "latest" you only keep one item and your sites can check the same feed to get that 1 item.

Comment: PPS: For playlists I'm talking about this URL: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=XXXXX which is different info from Channel uploads list (which is the older link I posted earlier)

Answer (score 0):

Use this service, I think it will be the easiest way: https://latestyoutu.be/

You can find your channel ID by clicking Settings, Advanced, and Account Information and paste it into the site. (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3250431). This is probably the most hassle-free way of doing what it seems you want to.

Comment: Jay, thank you so much for your response and willingness to help me. I love the simplicity of this solution. It definitely points to the latest video on my YouTube Channel. Is there a way to point it to a specific Playlist within my Channel?

Comment: I just found this code that seems like it might provide what I'm looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193230/always-get-latest-video-in-youtube-playlist

Comment: @JulesC Happy to help, I'm the creator of LatestYoutube! A little extra information, the service will update within 15 minutes of uploading a new video. It basically checks if the last update was at least 15 minutes ago and then updates whenever someone uses the link, as to not overload the Youtube servers. But looking at your question I'm not sure if ltstyt would be any help here.